# How to keep double quotes from being sanitized in a jQuery ajax request?

Tags: jquery, ajax

What I essentially need to do is pass something along the lines of this through an ajax request:

```
http://www.somesite.com/?q="something here"
```

The problem is that when the request is sent, the "s become %22 which doesn't work for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Please include the relevant client-side and server-side code

Comment: You should probably show us the code for your ajax call, not just the URL ?

Comment: what you are trying to do? please explain, this is a standard behavior of encoding URL

Comment: In my opinion, the real answer is that you shouldn't use a querystring at all. jQuery's $.ajax has a data option that will accept almost anything, like objects, arrays, json, strings etc. but without any code who knows what you're trying to do ?

Comment: Coming to this years later to pay respects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is the normal behavior. 
URL will be encoded, have a look [urlencode](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

Your server framework, should decode it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If that doesn't work then it sounds like the receiving code isn't obeying the rules of URL encoding.

My advice: fix the code on the web server so it can handle %22 the same way every other system does. While you're at it be prepared for spaces to be encoded as %20 or sometimes even "+", along with plenty of other rules.

Comment: In general cases, server side code encoding is capable enough to handle these type of encoding, for me issue seems something different

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi yes, it appears that the OP isn't using any standard server-side encoding, my guess is that the issue is a roll-your-own service.